# Worksheet.CommandButton generates Method not found error

Tags: excel, vba

For the following code I get this error

> Method or Data Member not found.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws1.CommandButton1   ' Error apears here
        'Set Top/Height/Width/Left
    End With
End Sub
```

The following code works:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1
         'Set Top/Height/Width/Left
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to write a shorter macro and not always write `Worksheets("...").CommandButton..`

Comment: To my knowledge I don't think you can reference the command button using the worksheet object method ie. `ws1.CommandButton1`. However, using `Worksheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1` you're specifying the command button location rather than a reference to an object.

Comment: @Dean Thanks for the information, unfortunately not really the answer i was hoping for. But good to know why this is not possible

Comment: I am sure someone with a deeper understanding will assist further :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following to do the same:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Sheet1.CommandButton1
    With obj   ' Error apears here
        'Set Top/Height/Width/Left
    End With

End Sub
```

What I'm doing in my example is using the the code name of the worksheet rather than the regular name.

I think the reason why the first version you posted doesn't work, is that CommandButton1 is not part of a worksheet's object model.

Comment: +1 for using code name. I think it is also important that you are declaring `Sheet1.CommandButton1` as an `Object`. The OP could do the same as `Sheets("Sheet1").CommanButton1` and set to object to get the same result.

Comment: thanks to you, this work fine, but for ten sheets and five to ten buttons on each, i have to dim a lot of object :/

Comment: @diem_L you can use a for loop to reset your objects, shouldn't be difficult

Comment: @Dean right, never thought about a loop right now, but yes, shouldn't be difficult. Thanks both to you, saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: No problem. @Dean Right you are about the other method. Would work as well.